# Set shipping postcode early before add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like the customers to be able to set their post code before adding a product to cart.
This post code is then saved and used to define available delivery methods.

I've made the following functions but it's not always working and I'm not sure about which Woocommerce methods should be used and what's the difference between them:

- `WC()->customer->set_shipping_postcode(...)` and `WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode()`
- `WC()->session->set('shipping_postcode', ...)` and `WC()->session->get('shipping_postcode')`
- `update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_postcode', ...)` and `get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_postcode', true)`

Also, I'm saving post code for billing and shipping cause I don't know if user has previously made an order and chosen to delivered it to a shipping address different than billing address.

---

```
function getDeliveryZipcode()
{
  $shipping_postcode = WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
  $billing_postcode = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode();
  return $shipping_postcode ? $shipping_postcode : $billing_postcode;
}

function setDeliveryZipcode()
{
  $zipcode = $_GET['zipcode'];

  // ...

  WC()->customer->set_shipping_postcode(wc_clean($zipcode));
  WC()->customer->set_billing_postcode(wc_clean($zipcode));
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, but there is something missing, to avoid any issues:

```
// Important: Early enable customer WC_Session 
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'wc_session_enabler' );
function wc_session_enabler() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
}

function getDeliveryZipcode()
{
    $shipping_postcode = WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
    $billing_postcode = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode();
    
    return ! empty($shipping_postcode) ? $shipping_postcode : $billing_postcode;
}

function setDeliveryZipcode()
{
    if ( isset($_GET['zipcode']) ) {
        WC()->customer->set_shipping_postcode(wc_clean($_GET['zipcode']));
        WC()->customer->set_billing_postcode(wc_clean($_GET['zipcode']));
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Here are the differences explained between `WC_Session`, `WC_Customer` and `WordPress` related to user data:

- `WC()->customer` is the `WC_Customer` Object that access the **registered user-data from a defined logged in user** (so the data that is stored on database `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables) or **it will read the session data for guests**.
- `WC()->session` is the data stored in `WooCommerce session` for any customers **or guests**, linked to a browser cookie and to database through `wp_woocommerce_sessions` table. **But note that "customer" WC session is enabled on the first add to cart.**
- The WordPress functions `get_user_meta()`, `set_user_meta()` and `update_user_meta()` allow to read / write / update user metadata from `wp_usermeta` table for a registered user.

> **Note:** The following doesn't exist in WooCommerce:

> ```
> $postcode = WC()->session->get('shipping_postcode');
> ```

```
WC()->session->set('shipping_postcode', $postcode);
```

The customer session data can be read using:

```
// Get an array of the current customer data stored in WC session
$customer_data = (array) WC()->session->get('customer'); 

// Get the billing postcode
if ( isset( $customer_data['postcode'] ) )
    $postcode = $customer_data['postcode']; 

// Get the shipping postcode
if ( isset( $customer_data['shipping_postcode'] ) )
    $postcode = $customer_data['shipping_postcode'];
```

The customer session data can be set for example using:

```
// Get an array of the current customer data stored in WC session
$customer_data = (array) WC()->session->get('customer'); 

// Change the billing postcode
$customer_data['postcode'] = '10670';

// Change the shipping postcode
$customer_data['shipping_postcode'] = '10670';

// Save the array of customer WC session data
WC()->session->set('customer', $customer_data);
```

For `WC()->customer`, you can use any of the [`WC_Customer` available getter and setter methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html), but some few methods will not work for guests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just needed a test for `is_admin()` in `wc_session_enabler()` to avoid an error in admin pages.

Comment: @fdehanne Yes you are completely right! I have updated this answer code.

Comment: It's also causing an error for API REST. I've tried to use constant `REST_REQUEST` but it seems to be initialized after `init` hook.
Moving `wc_session_enabler` to `parse_request` hook seems to work, but I don't know if this hook is relevant.

Comment: I@fdehanne Sorry I don't have the soluce for the moment, I didn't use that with REST API yet. if it works with parse_request hook, use it with it until we find something more relevant.

Comment: I used the action `init` a few months ago but I think it's too early as of today, September 27th, 2023. I changed to `woocommerce_init`.

Comment: I am also using `woocommerce_init` instead of `init`.