# WooCommerce not saving order meta data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to save some response data from a API as meta data in orders using the function below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_meta_data', 20, 1);
function add_meta_data( $order ) {
    $order->update_meta_data( 'meta_data_1', $_SESSION['meta_data_1'] );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'meta_data_2', $_SESSION['meta_data_2'] );
}
```

The meta data is not being saved immediately after we click on PURCHASE.

It's being saved either if I click twice on the button (thus completing the purchase), or if I get any error and need to click again on the button (thus, again, completing the purchase).

My intent is to add these values after the checkout, preferably after the payment has been finished.

Then I want to display said data in the order details page, as below (note the meta data lines with empty values):

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: You should use WC_Session instead of php $_SESSION… Note that  *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.**"*

Comment: Using WC_Session did not work for me, @LoicTheAztec. Would you need more code to make a better assessment? I just asked in the same manner others have asked similar questions to mine. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: That is because you need to force the WooCommerce session coockie to be set from start, before add to cart event. Most of people doesn't know that. Your actual provided code, context and details doesn't allow anybody to give ans useful answer to your issue.

Comment: Thank you again for your feedback, @LoicTheAztec. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: To early initiate WC_Sessions in the right way see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203171/3730754